# Can "none of them" denote two person

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

As I understand, *neither of them* is used to negate for two people. If you don't know whether there are two people or more than two, can *none of them* be possibly referring to *two people*. Or *none of them* always negates for more than two people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking *none* is for more than two. If there are only two, use *neither*.

> **Neither** of (the two of) them are wearing hats.
>
> **None** of that group are wearing hats.

If you don't know, then *none* is fine.

> A:  **None** of the boys packed a lunch for the trip.
>   B: You mean of the *two* boys?
>   A:  Yes, you're right.  **Neither** of them packed a lunch.